# LookUp Column Not Returning Values from Referenced List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, sharepoint-list, powerapp

I have two lists, A1 and B1.

A1 has and "Entity" column and the rest of the columns are user details.

A1 Example:

- Entity column = Starbucks..
- Rest of columns = Name, Request Date, Email, etc.

B1 also has an "Entity" column but the rest of the columns are Entity related data; Entity ID, Location, Size, etc.

I am trying to add a look up column to A1 that will say "Ok, the Entity is Starbucks, go to B1 and return the Entity ID, Location and Size to columns in A1.

I currently have a lookup column with the options below. I know I am missing something, none of the created columns are showing any data.

Column name:
Entity ID

The type of information in this column is:
Lookup

Additional Column Settings
Specify detailed options for the type of information you selected.

Description:

Require that this column contains information: No

Enforce unique values: No

Get information from: B1

In this column: Entity (linked to item)

Allow multiple values: not checked

Add a column to show each of these additional fields:

- Entity
- Entity (linked to item)
- Compliance Asset Id
- LMS Setup
- 2020 SNP Course
- **Entity ID**
- **Location**
- **Size**

---

I did create a power app - customized form but can't figure out how to do this their either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the below columns in the List B1

- Entity

[image]

- Entity (linked to item)

[image]

- LMS Setup
- 2020 SNP Course
- Entity ID
- Location : Location
- Size: Number

[image]

[image]

2.Create a Lookup column in the List A1

- Get information from: B1
- In this column: Entity ID

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]